# Replacing each row with a column

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given an array `X` of shape `(n, m)` and another given number `l` how can I get an array `Y` of shape `(n, l, m, l)` where `Y[i, j, :, :]` is the null matrix that has been replaced the `j`-th column by the `i`-th row of X.

For example, if

```
X = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 4, 5],
    [3, 4, 5, 6]])
l = 5
```

then

```
Y[2, 3] = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 4, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 6, 0]
])
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please show some of your array

Comment: Sorry, but that explanation does not make sense without an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.einsum`:

```
Y = np.zeros((n, l, m, l))
np.einsum('ijkj->jik', Y)[...] = X
```

Comment: Must be the single one most bizarre downvote I've collected.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to vectorize softmax function in svm.